# Reorder and reformat a table in R

Tags: r, formatting

I have a big table like this (this is just an excerpt from the original table which has thousands of functions (rows) and many samples (columns, except the first one)):

```
function    M123Q   OO987   LKJY11
phi            9       2     0
3R            74      71    65
GlcNAc         1       0     1
```

And I need to reorder it like this adding two extra columns ("total_hits" column is the sum of all the numbers from column "hits" which have the same "ID" and "Percentage" is the product of "hits"/"total_hits"):

```
ID    function  hits    total_hits  percentage
M123Q   phi      9         84       0.107142857
M123Q   3R       74        84       0.880952381
M123Q   GlcNAc   1         84       0.011904762
OO987   phi      2         73       0.02739726
OO987   3R       71        73       0.97260274
OO987   GlcNAc    0        73       0
LKJY11  phi       0        66       0
LKJY11  3R       65        66       0.984848485
LKJY11  GlcNAc    1        66       0.015151515
```

I'm currently using R, so I'd very much appreciate an R solution if possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do this where we reshape from 'wide' to 'long' (`pivot_longer`), grouped by 'ID', get the `sum` of 'hits' and the 'percentage'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -function., names_to = "ID", values_to = "hits") %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(total_hits = sum(hits), percentage = hits/total_hits)
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
#  function. ID      hits total_hits percentage
#  <chr>     <chr>  <int>      <int>      <dbl>
#1 phi       LKJY11     0         66     0     
#2 3R        LKJY11    65         66     0.985 
#3 GlcNAc    LKJY11     1         66     0.0152
#4 phi       M123Q      9         84     0.107 
#5 3R        M123Q     74         84     0.881 
#6 GlcNAc    M123Q      1         84     0.0119
#7 phi       OO987      2         73     0.0274
#8 3R        OO987     71         73     0.973 
#9 GlcNAc    OO987      0         73     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`function.` = c("phi", "3R", "GlcNAc"), M123Q = c(9L, 
74L, 1L), OO987 = c(2L, 71L, 0L), LKJY11 = c(0L, 65L, 1L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Reshape the dataframe long-ways:  

df1 <- data.frame(reshape(df1, 

        idvar = "function.",

        ids = unique(df1$function.),

        direction = "long",

        varying = names(df1)[names(df1) != "function."],

        v.names = "hits",

        times = names(df1)[names(df1) != "function."],

        timevar = "ID"), row.names = NULL)

# Groupwise summation of hits (by ID): 

df1$total_hits <- with(df1, ave(hits, ID, FUN = sum))

# Calculation of percentage: 

df1$percentage <- df1$hits/df1$total_hits
```